# android screen brightness does not update when using layoutparams

Tags: android, brightness

i have read that the screen brightness should update on the spot when i change it with layoutparams .

`//preview brightness changes at this window

                //get the current window attributes

                LayoutParams layoutpars = window.getAttributes();

                //set the brightness of this window

                layoutpars.screenBrightness = brightness / (float)255;

                //apply attribute changes to this window

                window.setAttributes(layoutpars);`

when when i tried it, it doesnt. i had to turn screen off and on again to set the brightness.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: be sure you're using WindowManager.LayoutParams. I assume you used getWindow() to get the value of window?

Comment: thats correct. i used getwindow(). i am also using windowmanager.layoutparams